# How do I ignore and continue past a SIGTRAP in GDB without causing slowdown?

Tags: c, gdb, signals

I have a situation within a C executable where GDB receives SIGTRAP and stops.

I have tried the following command, which *sort of* works:

```
handle SIGTRAP nostop noprint noignore
```

This results in GDB spamming:

```
"Can't send signals to this remote system. SIGTRAP not sent."
```

While this looks like an error, it doesn't seem to have any effect on the code itself; it just continues until the next breakpoint, but unfortunately does so very slowly.

Does anyone know how to make it silently do this? I know command has a silent option, but I don't know how to combine it with the handle command.

Comment: The obvious question would be "how do I fix this?", not "how do I work around this horrible error without losing speed?". Heh. I think that if the TRAP still happens, it's going to be slow, even if GDB ignored it more fully. Fix it?

Comment: @unwind Well his actual question is quite clear, and don't get why we would not answer it. If he wanted us to fix the real issue, I am sure he would have asked it directly. Anyway may be [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759129/why-does-ignoring-sigtrap-not-work-with-asm) can help you ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the trap is intentional and is part of the real time framework we're using. I am running this in a testing environment, which is why the trap is occurring; we want it to in this instance. But I also want to be able to debug around it to figure out what's going wrong elsewhere in the code *after* the trap occurs.

Comment: @Badda: stack overflow is dedicated to **enhance** code quality, not help bad code making its way into production (or a student's mind). So no, it is not to be answered, as it is clearly an XY-problem.

Comment: @EmileVictor: "Unfortunately, the trap is intentional and is part of the real time framework we're using" - Care to tell which framework it is so we can avoid it? It sounds like one of those 1970ies/80ies hacks no one confessed to be responsible for.

Comment: Is it in fact intentional that *`gdb`* receives these signals?  I could believe that the system is designed to regularly signal the program under test, but signaling gdb itself serves no useful purpose that I can see.  If you can configure an exception for `gdb` processes then that might be a good bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the choice about whether to handle, ignore, or pass through the signal is always done in GDB.  When the SIGTRAP is delivered your remote target stops and informs GDB that it stopped due to SIGTRAP.

As you've told gdb to pass through SIGTRAP then gdb tries to send the SIGTRAP back to the remote target as part of a continue command, however, it seems that your gdbserver is not accepting the signal, this is where the message is coming from, at this point gdb tries again to resume the remote target, but this time without the signal.

So, what you've done is correct, and should work, however, the gdbserver you're using does not appear to support resuming with signal, see the `C` and `S` packets on here https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Packets.html#Packets.

And... though your program may appear to be running fine with the warning being printed, I'd assume that the SIGTRAP being delivered should trigger some behaviour (context switch or whatever), well, that's not going to be happening as the signal will not be reaching your test program.